# Why does my code output <class '__main__.Dice1'>

Tags: python, python-3.x

While trying to roll 2 dice and testing out random number generation, I stumbled across a message that said <class '**main**.Dice1'> whenever I ran the code.

```
import random
RandomDice1 = random.randint(1,6)
RandomDice2 = random.randint(1,6)
RandomDiceTotal = RandomDice1 + RandomDice2
print("Face Value: %s" % RandomDiceTotal)
class Dice1:
    def __init__(self, face, dicenumber):
        self.face = RandomDice1
        self.dicenumber = RandomDice1
    def __str__(self):
        if self.dicernumber == 6:
            print(" ------\n| o  o |\n| o  o |\n| o  o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 5:
            print(" ------\n| o  o |\n|   o  |\n| o  o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 4:
            print(" ------\n| o  o |\n|      |\n| o  o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 3:
            print(" ------\n| o    |\n|   o  |\n|    o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 2:
            print(" ------\n| o    |\n|      |\n|    o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 1:
            print(" ------\n|      |\n|   o  |\n|      |\n ------")



print(Dice1)
```

Comment: Return the string(s) in `__str__()` instead of printing them.

Comment: Because `Dice1` is the name of your class.  It is not an OBJECT of that class.  I suspect you wanted `dice = Dice1()` / `print(dice)`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason you get that response is because you basically printing and objects location in memory.. make sense?

change your code from class to def and than run the code successfully..

```
import random
RandomDice1 = random.randint(1,6)
RandomDice2 = random.randint(1,6)
RandomDiceTotal = RandomDice1 + RandomDice2
print("Face Value: %s" % RandomDiceTotal)
def Dice1():
    def __init__(self, face, dicenumber):
        self.face = RandomDice1
        self.dicenumber = RandomDice1
    def __str__(self):
        if self.dicernumber == 6:
            print(" ------\n| o  o |\n| o  o |\n| o  o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 5:
            print(" ------\n| o  o |\n|   o  |\n| o  o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 4:
            print(" ------\n| o  o |\n|      |\n| o  o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 3:
            print(" ------\n| o    |\n|   o  |\n|    o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 2:
            print(" ------\n| o    |\n|      |\n|    o |\n ------")
        elif RandomDice1 == 1:
            print(" ------\n|      |\n|   o  |\n|      |\n ------")



Dice1()
```